# how to show the cursor coordinates in wxPython when using wx.SplitterWindow

Tags: matplotlib, wxpython, marker

I'm trying to do something similar to that shown in this [link](https://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/wxcursor_demo.html) to draw a cursor and report the data coordinates in the status bar. However, my code is a little bit different since I need to use wx.SplitterWindow to separate buttons and plots. Basically, in the main frame module I create the status bar, but the plot is generated in a separated module. See below my current code:

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import \
    FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigCanvas, \
    NavigationToolbar2WxAgg as NavigationToolbar, \
    wxc as wxc

import pylab
import wx
from numpy import arange, sin, pi

class data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.t = []
        self.s = []

class Plot_Panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        # create some sizers
        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        checkSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        # create figrue
        self.fig = Figure()
        self.canvas = FigCanvas(self, -1, self.fig)
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)

        # create the widgets
        self.toggleMarker = wx.CheckBox(self, label="Show Marker")

        # layout the widgets
        mainSizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        checkSizer.Add(self.toggleMarker, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        mainSizer.Add(checkSizer)
        self.SetSizer(mainSizer)

    def draw_plot(self, data):
        # Clear the previous figure
        self.fig.clear()

        # Redraw figure
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)

        # Define data to plot
        self.plot_data= self.axes.plot(data.t, data.s, linewidth=3, color='y',)[0]

        # Draw Cursor or not
        if self.toggleMarker.IsChecked():
            # Note that event is a MplEvent
            self.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.UpdateStatusBar)
            self.canvas.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW, self.ChangeCursor)

        self.canvas.draw()

    def ChangeCursor(self, event):
        self.canvas.SetCursor(wxc.StockCursor(wx.CURSOR_BULLSEYE))

    def UpdateStatusBar(self, event):
        if event.inaxes:
            x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
            # self.statusBar.SetStatusText(("x= "+str(Pos.x)+"  y="+str(Pos.y)))


class Button_Panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        # create the widgets
        self.toggleStart = wx.Button(self, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Plot data")


class ProportionalSplitter(wx.SplitterWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent, id = -1, proportion=0.66, size = wx.DefaultSize, **kwargs):
        wx.SplitterWindow.__init__(self,parent,id,wx.Point(0, 0),size, **kwargs)
        self.SetMinimumPaneSize(50) #the minimum size of a pane.
        self.proportion = proportion
        if not 0 < self.proportion < 1:
            raise ValueError, "proportion value for ProportionalSplitter must be between 0 and 1."
        self.ResetSash()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnReSize)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SPLITTER_SASH_POS_CHANGED, self.OnSashChanged, id=id)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.firstpaint = True

    def SplitHorizontally(self, win1, win2):
        if self.GetParent() is None: return False
        return wx.SplitterWindow.SplitHorizontally(self, win1, win2,
            int(round(self.GetParent().GetSize().GetHeight() * self.proportion)))

    def SplitVertically(self, win1, win2):
        if self.GetParent() is None: return False
        return wx.SplitterWindow.SplitVertically(self, win1, win2,
            int(round(self.GetParent().GetSize().GetWidth() * self.proportion)))

    def GetExpectedSashPosition(self):
        if self.GetSplitMode() == wx.SPLIT_HORIZONTAL:
            tot = max(self.GetMinimumPaneSize(),self.GetParent().GetClientSize().height)
        else:
            tot = max(self.GetMinimumPaneSize(),self.GetParent().GetClientSize().width)
        return int(round(tot * self.proportion))

    def ResetSash(self):
        self.SetSashPosition(self.GetExpectedSashPosition())

    def OnReSize(self, event):
        "Window has been resized, so we need to adjust the sash based on self.proportion."
        self.ResetSash()
        event.Skip()

    def OnSashChanged(self, event):
        "We'll change self.proportion now based on where user dragged the sash."
        pos = float(self.GetSashPosition())
        if self.GetSplitMode() == wx.SPLIT_HORIZONTAL:
            tot = max(self.GetMinimumPaneSize(),self.GetParent().GetClientSize().height)
        else:
            tot = max(self.GetMinimumPaneSize(),self.GetParent().GetClientSize().width)
        self.proportion = pos / tot
        event.Skip()

    def OnPaint(self, event):
        if self.firstpaint:
            if self.GetSashPosition() != self.GetExpectedSashPosition():
                self.ResetSash()
            self.firstpaint = False
        event.Skip()

class Main_Window(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title = title)

        # Create a StatusBar at the bottom of the window
        self.statusBar = wx.StatusBar(self, -1)
        self.SetStatusBar(self.statusBar)

        # Set plot panel
        self.splitter = ProportionalSplitter(self,-1, 0.85)
        self.ppanel = Plot_Panel(self.splitter)
        self.ppanel.SetBackgroundColour('#ffffff')

        # Set button panel                           
        self.bpanel = Button_Panel(self.splitter)

        # Set frame 
        self.splitter.SplitVertically(self.ppanel, self.bpanel)
        self.Show(True)
        self.Maximize(True)  

        # bind the widgets
        self.ppanel.toggleMarker.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.onToggleMarker)
        self.bpanel.toggleStart.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onToggleStart)        

        # Set classes
        self.data = data()


    def onToggleMarker(self, event):
        self.ppanel.draw_plot(self.data)

    def onToggleStart(self, event):

        self.data.t = arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.01)
        self.data.s = sin(2*2*pi*self.data.t)

        # plot data
        self.ppanel.draw_plot(self.data)


def main():
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = Main_Window(None, "GUI")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()


if __name__ == "__main__" :
    main()
```

The plot is shown when the button "Plot data" is pressed. What I would like to do is to show the x and y position in the status bar when the checkbox "Show Marker" is checked (in a similar way as it is done in the code posted in the link), and stop when it is unchecked. But I'm not sure if it is possible to do it in my code due to having the definitions of the status bar and the plot in different modules. Any hint will be welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What a joy to get a full, working example program with the question.
You just need to pass the base module as a parameter to `self.ppanel`
i.e.

```
self.ppanel = Plot_Panel(self.splitter, self)
```

then refer to that when updating the status bar, see below for references to `base`

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import \
    FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigCanvas, \
    NavigationToolbar2WxAgg as NavigationToolbar, \
    wxc as wxc

import pylab
import wx
from numpy import arange, sin, pi

class data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.t = []
        self.s = []

class Plot_Panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, base):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.base = base
        # create some sizers
        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        checkSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        # create figrue
        self.fig = Figure()
        self.canvas = FigCanvas(self, -1, self.fig)
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)

        # create the widgets
        self.toggleMarker = wx.CheckBox(self, label="Show Marker")

        # layout the widgets
        mainSizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        checkSizer.Add(self.toggleMarker, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        mainSizer.Add(checkSizer)
        self.SetSizer(mainSizer)

    def draw_plot(self, data):
        # Clear the previous figure
        self.fig.clear()

        # Redraw figure
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)

        # Define data to plot
        self.plot_data= self.axes.plot(data.t, data.s, linewidth=3, color='y',)[0]

        # Draw Cursor or not
        if self.toggleMarker.IsChecked():
            # Note that event is a MplEvent
            self.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.UpdateStatusBar)
            self.canvas.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW, self.ChangeCursor)

        self.canvas.draw()

    def ChangeCursor(self, event):
        self.canvas.SetCursor(wxc.StockCursor(wx.CURSOR_BULLSEYE))

    def UpdateStatusBar(self, event):
        if event.inaxes:
            x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
            self.base.statusBar.SetStatusText(("x= "+str(x)+"  y="+str(y)))

class Button_Panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        # create the widgets
        self.toggleStart = wx.Button(self, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Plot data")


class ProportionalSplitter(wx.SplitterWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent, id = -1, proportion=0.66, size = wx.DefaultSize, **kwargs):
        wx.SplitterWindow.__init__(self,parent,id,wx.Point(0, 0),size, **kwargs)
        self.SetMinimumPaneSize(50) #the minimum size of a pane.
        self.proportion = proportion
        if not 0 < self.proportion < 1:
            raise ValueError, "proportion value for ProportionalSplitter must be between 0 and 1."
        self.ResetSash()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnReSize)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SPLITTER_SASH_POS_CHANGED, self.OnSashChanged, id=id)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.firstpaint = True

    def SplitHorizontally(self, win1, win2):
        if self.GetParent() is None: return False
        return wx.SplitterWindow.SplitHorizontally(self, win1, win2,
            int(round(self.GetParent().GetSize().GetHeight() * self.proportion)))

    def SplitVertically(self, win1, win2):
        if self.GetParent() is None: return False
        return wx.SplitterWindow.SplitVertically(self, win1, win2,
            int(round(self.GetParent().GetSize().GetWidth() * self.proportion)))

    def GetExpectedSashPosition(self):
        if self.GetSplitMode() == wx.SPLIT_HORIZONTAL:
            tot = max(self.GetMinimumPaneSize(),self.GetParent().GetClientSize().height)
        else:
            tot = max(self.GetMinimumPaneSize(),self.GetParent().GetClientSize().width)
        return int(round(tot * self.proportion))

    def ResetSash(self):
        self.SetSashPosition(self.GetExpectedSashPosition())

    def OnReSize(self, event):
        "Window has been resized, so we need to adjust the sash based on self.proportion."
        self.ResetSash()
        event.Skip()

    def OnSashChanged(self, event):
        "We'll change self.proportion now based on where user dragged the sash."
        pos = float(self.GetSashPosition())
        if self.GetSplitMode() == wx.SPLIT_HORIZONTAL:
            tot = max(self.GetMinimumPaneSize(),self.GetParent().GetClientSize().height)
        else:
            tot = max(self.GetMinimumPaneSize(),self.GetParent().GetClientSize().width)
        self.proportion = pos / tot
        event.Skip()

    def OnPaint(self, event):
        if self.firstpaint:
            if self.GetSashPosition() != self.GetExpectedSashPosition():
                self.ResetSash()
            self.firstpaint = False
        event.Skip()

class Main_Window(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title = title)

        # Create a StatusBar at the bottom of the window
        self.statusBar = wx.StatusBar(self, -1)
        self.SetStatusBar(self.statusBar)

        # Set plot panel
        self.splitter = ProportionalSplitter(self,-1, 0.85)
        self.ppanel = Plot_Panel(self.splitter, self)
        self.ppanel.SetBackgroundColour('#ffffff')

        # Set button panel
        self.bpanel = Button_Panel(self.splitter)

        # Set frame
        self.splitter.SplitVertically(self.ppanel, self.bpanel)
        self.Show(True)
        self.Maximize(True)

        # bind the widgets
        self.ppanel.toggleMarker.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.onToggleMarker)
        self.bpanel.toggleStart.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onToggleStart)

        # Set classes
        self.data = data()


    def onToggleMarker(self, event):
        self.ppanel.draw_plot(self.data)

    def onToggleStart(self, event):

        self.data.t = arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.01)
        self.data.s = sin(2*2*pi*self.data.t)

        # plot data
        self.ppanel.draw_plot(self.data)


def main():
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = Main_Window(None, "GUI")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()


if __name__ == "__main__" :
    main()
```

[image]